# Admob Interstitial ad closes automatically

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I'm using test id for admob interstitial ad in my app, the ad is fine in the emulator but when i test it on a real device, sometimes it displays a black screen and sometimes it shows a test ad, when it does show a test ad the ad closes automatically. 
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add some code examples on how and when you are showing the interstitial ad

Comment: I load the ad in the onBindViewHolder of the adapter and then show it when a recyclerview item is tapped. The ad appears but sometimes its just black screen and when its not just a black screen the ad closes automatically.